# Regular expression to extract operands and operators along with parenthesis from a logical expression

Tags: jquery, regex, expression, string-matching, string-parsing

```
ABC or DEF and ( GHI or JKL)
```

Here, the operand ABC can be a phrase which may contain spaces. The only operators are `and`, `or`. Can anyone suggest a way to fetch all the operands?

I thought to do it this way:
There will be a list of operators which I will use as reference to find the first index of any of this `\bOPERATOR\b` and then find the first index of next available   `\bOPERATOR\b` and extract a word between these 2 operators (by manipulating index depending on found operator's length)

I feel this is the brute force way of doing this. Can anyone suggest a better solution? I would prefer if that could be done using jQuery.

Comment: it's a kind difficult to understand what are the operators you mean, could you wrap each one in backticks to improve readability?

Comment: I have to fetch ABC, DEF, GHI and JKL from that expression

Comment: `The only operators are and, or` what about the brackets?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion I removed those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var expression = "ABC or DEF and ( GHI or JKL)";
var tokens = expression.split(/ and | or |\(|\)/);
tokens = tokens.filter(function(token) { return token.trim().length > 0; });
```

Explanation:

The regular expression splits the expression by:
1) "and" or "or" surrounded by spaces (to distinguish these operators from parts of words, like "stand" or "fork").
2) Open and close parentheses.

The call to `filter` removes extraneous empty strings and strings containing only spaces, which can be produced if multiple separators occur consecutively (as when "and" is followed by a parenthesized subexpression in your example).

Comment: expression.split(/ and | or |\(|\)/); I guess doesn't work.. but I tried the solution mentioned below

Comment: You need backslashes before the parentheses, which otherwise have special meaning in a regular expression.

Comment: what could be the solution if you want to return operators as well ??

Comment: expression.split(/\s+/) will break up the string into all non-space components.  But, in your OP you said that the operands could contain spaces, and this code will break up such operands into multiple parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
var separators = ["\\bAND\\b" , "\\b(\\b", "\\bOR\\b", "\\b)\\b"];
var operands = expression.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|')));
```

Comment: This should work as well, but you will still need to filter out empty and all-space strings.

Comment: @phari What can be done if you don't want to split on parenthesis if they are part of operands? Say for eg: A OR BC(D). The split here should return 
1. A
2. OR
3. BC(D)